# HTML/CSS div matching left % and width of div above

Tags: html, css

I feel this is probably a really stupid question, and I should know the answer, but I can't seem to find it and it's really bugging me.

I have a page, where I have a section followed by an article, but the article is set to left: 40% and the article is following this, but I can't work out how to stop it. Below is the JSFiddle for it so any help as to how to make the article ignore

```
left: 40%;
```

and just set it to

```
width:100%;
```

without the left margin.

http://jsfiddle.net/x30jayzv/

Thanks.

Comment: You have multiple errors in your HTML, some tags are not closed (especially img tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 28 you have unclosed `section` tag, missing the end-bracket.

```
</section>
         ^
```

Comment: Oh gosh, thanks, that fixed it, that was really stupid of me. Thanks for pointing that out.